# PostgreSQL function to return text array with two elements

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to return a text array with two elements using postgresql function.  But the output seems to generate one element.

Here's result from pgAdmin query:  Here, it does seem like the result array with two elements

```
select "address_pts".usp_etl_gis_get_cname_bd_ext(3)
ALLEGHANY,POLYGON((1308185.61436242 959436.119048506,1308185.61436242 1036363.17188701,1441421.26094835 1036363.17188701,1441421.26094835 959436.119048506,1308185.61436242 959436.119048506))
```

But in Python when I call the function, I see the output array length as only 1.

```
(partial python code)
pg_cur.execute("SELECT \"VA\".address_pts.usp_etl_gis_get_cname_bd_ext(3)")
for rec in pg_cur:
   print(len(rec))
-- output = 1

for rec in pg_cur:
   print(rec[0])
-- ouput: ['ALLEGHANY', 'POLYGON((1308185.61436242 959436.119048506,1308185.61436242 1036363.17188701,1441421.26094835 1036363.17188701,1441421.26094835 959436.119048506,1308185.61436242 959436.119048506))']

 it generates an error for below code:
 for rec in pg_cur:
   print(rec[1]) 

-- Here is the function --  
-- postgresql 9.6

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION address_pts.usp_etl_gis_get_cname_bd_ext(
_cid integer
  )
RETURNS TEXT[]
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100.0
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $function$


DECLARE cname TEXT;
DECLARE cbd_ext TEXT;
DECLARE outarr TEXT[];

BEGIN    
IF (_cid NOT BETWEEN 1 and 100) THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '%s IS NOT A VALID COUNTY ID. ENTER A COUNTY BETWEEN 1..100', _cid;
END IF;


select upper(rtrim(ltrim(replace(name10,' ','_'))))
into cname
from "jurisdictions"."CB_TIGER_2010"
WHERE county_id = _cid;

/* 
#Returns the float4 minimum bounding box for the supplied geometry, 
#as a geometry. The polygon is defined by the corner points of the 
#bounding box ((MINX, MINY), (MINX, MAXY), (MAXX, MAXY), (MAXX, MINY), (MINX, MINY)). 
#(PostGIS will add a ZMIN/ZMAX coordinate as well).
*/

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Envelope(geom))
INTO cbd_ext
from "jurisdictions"."CB_TIGER_2010"
where county_id = _cid;

outarr[0] := cname::text;
outarr[1] := cbd_ext::text;

RETURN outarr;

END;

$function$;
```

questions:

1. Is postgresql function resulting in array of length 1 or 2?
2. If len is 1, how can split the result? for example:
   ['ALLEGHANY','POLYGON((1308185.614362,...))']

Thank you

Comment: as you define it here - should be array with two elements - why dont you try?..

Comment: Vao, print(len(rec)) is 1.  which makes me believe output has one combined element.

Comment: I assume `pg_cur` interprets postgres `text[]` as `text`, thus you have string instead of array and length is 1

Comment: Any suggestions on how to split the text at the first ',' into an array in python?  Ty

Comment: sorry - I'm from postgres, not python

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to split the string once you are in Python, you can try with `regex` and the module `re`:

```
# Python3
import re
p = re.compile(r"\['(.*)','(.*)']")
res = p.search("['ALLEGHANY','POLYGON((1308185.614362,...))']")

print(res.group(1)) # 'ALLEGHANY'
print(res.group(2)) # 'POLYGON((1308185.614362,...))'
```